# Node js server for Ember Data

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data

I have the sample "todo" ember application working with LSAdapter; now i'm attempting to use the RESTAdapter and get the json data from node js;

In the Ember application i've done:

```
Todos.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  url: "http://127.0.0.1"
});



Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

And this is the main route handler:

```
Todos.TodosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Todos.Todo.find();
    }
});
```

In ember data documentation they say that this should send an http request GET to url/todos, so in this case to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/todos
```

So i've made a Server with node js:

```
dispatcher.onGet("/todos", function(req, res) {
    bind.toFile('tmpl/todos.tpl', {

            id: "1",
            title: 'Just a try',
            is_completed: "false"

    }, function(data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(data);
    });
});
```

It uses httpdispatcher and bind modules from npm, and works because if i type in the browser:

```
//url in the browser
127.0.0.1/todos
```

i get:

```
{ "todo": { "id": 1, "title": Just a try, "is_completed": false } }
```

But if i execute the app in the browser (URL: file:///D:/Works/Web%20Resources/EMBER%20MVC%20FRAMEWORK/Prova_App/index.html) the todo "Just a try" is not loaded;
inspecting with chrome, in the console tab, i can read an error that says "Failed to load resource   file:///D:/todos"

Can someone help to figure this out?

Comment: Try starting chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a file:///? You need to request the page via the server.

When ember looks for the todos its checking the root of the domain. When requesting via a web address that is [address]/todos. When you use a file:/// request that becomes `file:///D:/todos`.

Comment: You're extremely right; now i've configured the node js server in order to have the ember appa accessible at the address: http://127.0.0.1/static/ember_app/index.html    and the json output is still working at http://127.0.0.1/todos but i still cannot see the todo in the app; in any case the error is no more there...

Comment: Ok, after you drove me in the right direction, i've figured out that the remaining errors were due to an incorrect json output, that in my case should be: { "todos": [{ "id": 1, "title": "Just a try", "is_completed": "false" }] }           Many thanks for help